# Example of non-commutative ring without unit such that...

Tags: ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of a non-commutative ring without unity such that $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$, for all $x,y\in R$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979474/proving-ring-r-with-unity-is-commutative-if-xy2-x2y2

Answer (score 3):

In the ring of $2\times2$ matrices with even entries, considered modulo $16$, we have $ABCD=0$ for all elements $A,B,C,D$. No unit element, not commutative.